# How can I dump the output of this register , the MSR - IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2 , to see whether unrestricted guest mode is supported/enabled?

Tags: windows, cpu, assembly

How can I dump the output of this register , the MSR -  IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2 , to see whether unrestricted guest mode is supported/enabled?

Context is curiosity.

I'm aware that Docker in the case of mac osx, and maybe in the case of Windows, requires unrestricted mode / unrestricted guest mode.

And I read

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/virtualization-software-development/topic/277958

"There are a series of MSRs that tell you if a given CPU supports the '1' setting of unrestricted guest and a number of other virtualization features. The specific MSR is IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2 and I believe unrestricted guest is bit 7 in the secondary proc controls VMCS field."

i don't know if powershell or wmic will show it.  I know win7 32bit has debug(which might possible show it?  know debug can show some registers, I have once used debug to move a value into the AX register), though i'm on win7 64bit and that doesn't have debug.

Perhaps somebody that knows a bit of assembly can show what assembler one needs to install and what lines to run, to display the bits of that register?

I'm not really quite enough into assembly to be asking on stackoverflow 'cos at this stage i'm coming at this right now from a 'superuser' angle.

Comment: This question is well suited for https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/. Moderators may help.

Comment: @Biswapriyo  ok so maybe the question is but then, question aside,  am I suitable for reverseengineering site, when I haven't even installed or used an assembler? would answers assume any prior/pre-requisite knowledge?

Comment: For example, OP [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19693) didn't install any assembler.

Comment: @Biswapriyo ok thanks. I will ask a different but related question there in a few days, though will leave this one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am assuming that there is some tool available in Windows to read and write MSRs as there is one for Linux [msr-tools](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/msr-tools/index.html). The tool gives you two command `rdmsr` and `wrmsr`. One can read the value of MSRs using `rdmsr` command. Here is [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/rdmsr--read-msr-) to one such tool for Window.**

There are two VM-execution controls for processor-based execution- Primary Processor-based VM-execution Controls (`IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS`) and Secondary Processor-based VM-execution Controls (`IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2`). The Unrestricted Guest mode bit is a part of `IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2`(as already mentioned in the question). The Secondary Processor-based VM-execution Controls is available only when bit 63 of `IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS` is 1. (Refer Sec 24.6.2 in [Intel SDM](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3c-part-3-manual.pdf))

So we need to first read `IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS` using `rdmsr` and check if bit 63 is 1 or not. If the bit value is **1** then read `IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2` using the same command.

The address for both the MSRs are as follows:

```
IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS  - 482H
IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2 - 48BH
```

Command in Linux:

```
sudo rdmsr 0x482 // To read IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS
sudo rdmsr 0x48B // To read IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2
```

The output for the `rdmsr` command is in hexadecimal and we can manually convert that to binary or can use some online tool for the same.

Now we need to check the bit for Unrestricted Guest in `IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2` and for that, we need to check the bit at position 7(as shown in the following image).

**Adding the full `IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2` structure, just in case you want to check other options too.**

[image]